# File format and settings for speech recording with small file size and keeping a decent quality

Tags: compression, app, speech, file, android

I use my Android phone to record speeches very often.

I would like to know what is the most recommended file format for speech recording considering I would like to minimize the file size but keep a good volume and quality, and what settings to use.

In case there is a recommended Android APP for this, I would appreciate the name!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ogg Vorbis doesn't suffer from much of the horriffic issues that occur with MP3, and generally produces smaller files.

[Hi Quality Voice Recorder](http://appcrawlr.com/android/hi-quality-voice-recorder-mp3) will do what you want.

If you need smaller, obviously gsm which is the encoding used for mobile phone calls should be suffficient, but there is less software compatible with this format.